# Prevent drawables with transparency from overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I was wondering if it's possible to have a drawable (A) with a set alpha on top of another drawable (B) while preventing them from overlapping (B under A is hidden)? I have created illustrations below:

Here's what typically happens when two drawables with alpha enabled overlap (color of B mixes with color of A):

[image]

However, I would like the circle (A) to completely hide the underlying drawable (B):

[image]

Eventually what I want to do with it is to create a highlight effect with the background appearing to create shadow around a particular view/icon:

[image]

I have looked into ShapeDrawable, LayerDrawable, and VectorDrawable, but I'm not sure how to achieve this either in xml or programmatically.

Comment: use https://github.com/emmaguy/dynamic-svg-colours library, It might help you with `VectorDrawables`

Comment: @Rohit Thank you for the link, but I think this only changes the colors of an svg (and VectorDrawables?) dynamically. It doesn't solve the issue of overlapping drawables with transparency...

Comment: For transperancy, you can add alpha colors to svg colors

Comment: @Rohit Okay, I tried to open it in Android Studio, but it said that the plugin was outdated.

Comment: I think, in dependencies, you need to update compile to implementation and some new gradle changes.